# What is the proper way to handle html5 video tags in an MVVM manner?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, durandal

In our Durandal based SPA, I need an html5 video player that is heavily controlled by my view model.  The view model will control playback, seeking, time displays, changing the source etc...  In order to do this my viewmodel needs to have a direct reference to the html video node so it can access properties and functions on the video tag.

Now the easiest way to do this would be to add an empty video tag to my view and use jquery to get a reference to it in my view model's `compositionComplete()` function.  However, this is now tightly coupling my view model to my view.

Is there any way for me to create the html tag in my view model (via `document.createElement('video')`), set that as a property of my view model, and then have knockout add that to the page?  According to the knockoutjs' documentation, the `html:` data bind clause will `.ToString()` the tag to the `innerHtml` property, and thus the javascript would not hold a direct reference to the same video tag that is represented on the page.

What would be the proper way to do this in an MVVM manner, or is my best bet to just pull the video tag out with jquery?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

After looking at knockout bindings further, I think the best solution is to create custom bindings per video method and attribute:

```
<video data-bind='sources: sourcesArr, volume: videoVolume, playback: playbackState, ...'> </video>
```

sourcesArr would be an observable array

volume would be an observable integer

playbackState would be an observable string with either 'play' or 'pause' value

**Original**

I think (maybe) you could create a video view model and video custom bindings like so

```
<video data-bind='video: videoViewModel'> </video>
```

Comment: Based on your original answer I was able to correctly solve the original issue by creating a custom binding that called valueAccessor(element), which set my view model property to the tag.  This allows me to gain access to any number of tags I create in the view and have them visible to the viewModel.  Your edit is an interesting idea, but I'm not sure how I'd call methods on the element like Play(), Pause(), etc...

Comment: Create another custom binding, say `el`, whose `init` function simply sets its target to its `element` parameter.

Comment: Yup, calling the methods is a pain. Here is the plackback custom binding: http://jsfiddle.net/k8SFc/. If I were to do this in WPF, I would provide events in my VM which the view will listen to but I don't see any KnockoutJS bindings implementing that approach. The easier way (and what I would also do to save time) is to just get the element as you and @ebohlman suggested but I don't think it's pure MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

Followup to my comment on LostInComputer's answer:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.el={
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    valueAccessor()(element);
  }
};
```

use as:

```
<video data-bind="el: myVideoElement, ..."></video>
```

Now `myVideoElement()` will give you the DOM element for the video.

Comment: Yep, that's the solution I ended up coming up with based on LostInComputer's original answer actually.